# Empty entries (***) when using traceroute on a PC but not when using traceroute in the router

Tags: networking, routing, traceroute

Today when I try to traceroute `www.google.com` from both my router and my PC, I saw a weird behavior.

Router's Traceroute

```
traceroute to www.google.com (173.194.38.176), 30 hops max, 40 byte packets
 1  10.74.128.182 (10.74.128.182)  69.669 ms 10.74.128.178 (10.74.128.178)  36.885 ms 10.74.128.182 (10.74.128.182)  38.042 ms
 2  10.74.128.181 (10.74.128.181)  36.468 ms  37.848 ms  35.048 ms
 3  10.64.7.74 (10.64.7.74)  75.262 ms 10.64.7.86 (10.64.7.86)  44.339 ms  40.346 ms
 4  kph-148-48.tm.net.my (203.106.148.48)  40.021 ms  48.847 ms  39.153 ms
 5  10.64.7.90 (10.64.7.90)  41.705 ms  42.232 ms  40.001 ms
 6  10.55.34.234 (10.55.34.234)  48.969 ms  48.335 ms  49.216 ms
 7  * * 72.14.203.186 (72.14.203.186)  47.921 ms
 8  209.85.242.240 (209.85.242.240)  61.557 ms  61.469 ms  47.117 ms
 9  209.85.242.232 (209.85.242.232)  59.473 ms  61.54 ms  55.777 ms
10  72.14.233.105 (72.14.233.105)  64.806 ms  61.513 ms  59.459 ms
11  sin04s02-in-f16.1e100.net (173.194.38.176)  61.45 ms  56.76 ms  55.513 ms
```

PC's Traceroute

```
Tracing route to www.google.com [173.194.38.179] over a maximum of 30 hops:
  1     1 ms    <1 ms     1 ms  router.asus.com [192.168.1.1] 
  2   118 ms    81 ms   118 ms  10.74.128.178 
  3    38 ms    37 ms    39 ms  10.74.128.177 
  4    45 ms    50 ms    72 ms  10.64.7.86 
  5    43 ms    41 ms    41 ms  kph-148-48.tm.net.my [203.106.148.48] 
  6     *        *        *     Request timed out.
  7     *        *        *     Request timed out.
  8     *        *        *     Request timed out.
  And onwards like that…

  Trace complete.
```

1. Why are there two different addresses (`10.74.128.182` and `10.74.128.178`)? Does that mean the packet is routed to 2 different routers at different time? If that's the case why the `tracert` command on my PC(Windows 7) did not shown it?
2. In the router's traceroute, both the IPs of the first and second trace (`10.74.128.178` and `10.74.128.181`) are in the same network address since it is class A IP and classified by the first 8 bits which is 10. Therefore I just wonder how a packet can be send to two routers that are in the same network?
3. Why the `tracert` command on my PC shows empty result `*` after `kph-148-48.tm.net.my [203.106.148.48]`whereas full traces were captured by the router `tracert` command?
4. In the router's traceroute, after line 4 which is a public address (`203.106.148.481`), the next 2 hops are private addresses (`10.64.7.90` and `10.55.34.234`). After that it changed back to public address which belongs to google (`72.14.203.186`). I thought private address suppose to be non-routable on the Internet? When I try to ping that 2 private addresses I did received reply. So I just wonder how is it possible for my pc to be able to reach the IPs at the private networks that come after a public address.

Comment: Hmm. I've never seen a traceroute from a router. What router do you have?

Comment: 10.0.0.0 - 10.255.255.255 is a private range IP address so that is in your local network

Comment: Question 2 is pointless, the reference to 'Class A' address space refers to an obsolete standard and is not in practice any more.  Also since the IP's are in the same /24... there are multiple ways to connect two (or more) routers to a single subnet and have them work together to provide redundancy.

Comment: @DavidPostill it's an Asus router that has a traceroute tool pre-installed

Comment: @DavidPostill the routers with private range ip 10.0.0.0 - 10.255.255.255 belongs to the ISP. I suspect they installed NAT router(s) in between my home router and the real public IP for my Internet access which is kph-148-48.tm.net.my (203.106.148.48). Because this is the IP I got in ipchicken.com

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Traceroute works by sending out IP packets with successively higher IP TTL (time to live) values: 1,2,3... Each hop decrements the TTL. When it reaches 0, the packet is not routed, and an ICMP time exceeded message is sent to to the source, which is how the system running traceroute determines the route.

1. This appears to be the traceroute version found on many Linux installations. This traceroute command sends out three packets for each TTL value. So what you are seeing is that two of the packets went to `10.74.128.182` and one went to `10.74.128.178`.
2. Since this is the first hop after your router, it is probably the router's gateway address. It is possible that HSRP or similar is in play: there are probably two devices load balancing with a floating IP address. For example: you use the gateway address 10.0.0.1, but behind the scenes this actually points to `10.0.0.2` and `10.0.0.3` which share the load. This is in fact [possible using HSRP](http://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/support/docs/ip/hot-standby-router-protocol-hsrp/13781-7.html). Classful routing is not really in use anymore. the 10.0.0.0/8 range is just RFC1918 IP addresses your ISP is using.
3. Different versions of traceroute send different packets out. The Linux version you're using on the router sends UDP packets by default; the windows version on your PC sends pings. It looks like the pings are being blocked between hops 5 and 6, but that's just a guess. Try a different traceroute utility on your PC and I bet you'll get different results.
4. You are right. RFC1918 addresses are not routable on the public internet. So my answer is that even though you see a public IP address at hop 4, you have not left your ISP yet. If you had, you shouldn't be able to get TTL expired messages with private source addresses. The similar IP addressing in hops 3 and 5 suggests this too: they both use addresses in `10.64.7.0/24` (probably not a coincidence). Suffice it to say this: the IP addresses are pretty much arbitrary, and within their own network, your ISP is free to have routers that have interfaces with both public and private interfaces. This is the case with hops 3 and 4. It's also possible for a packet to pass through routers without public IP addresses after leaving your ISPs network; in this case you should not receive a traceroute reply.

Comment: thanks for your precious insight, do you mind answer the newly added question 4? Thanks

Comment: Edited. Hopefully that answer is sufficient. Really the "TL;DR" is "it's not the 'internet'" yet. I had trouble being concise.

Comment: As a general side note: installing Wireshark/tcpdump and looking at your 'traceroute' packets on the wire is a great way to gain insight. And regarding #3, you could try using nmap/zenmap to send out TCP traceroutes.